# Why is automorphism composition associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could someone provide a simple explanation of why automorphism composition is associative? In my textbook, this is stated as 'trivial' but can't see the logic behind it..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Automorphism of what ?

Comment: In general the composition (of arrows) is associative.

Comment: Field automorphisms @Nitrogen

Comment: Because, in the end, composition of automorphisms is a composition of functions, which is associative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f,g,h$ be automorphisms of, say, some vector space $V$, but it really does not matter as the result is true for any maps.

You want to show that $f \circ (g \circ h ) = (f \circ g) \circ h$. 
Thus, take some $v \in V$ and compute the value it gets assigned. In both cases you will find it to be $f(g(h(v)))$. Thus the maps are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove that the composition of function is associative in general (i.e., for sets). Let $f:X\to Y,g:Y\to Z, h:Z\to W$  be functions. That is $f\subset X\times Y,g\subset Y\times Z,h\subset Z \times W$ such that for example, for $x\in X$, there is a unique $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$.

Composition is defined by, for example, $$gf=\{(x,z)\mid \exists y\in Y,(x,y)\in f, (y,z)\in g\}\subset X\times Z.$$ It is now a simple matter of set theory to show that $(hg)f=h(gf)$.